# How to server wordpress from SSL and non-SSL URLs

Tags: urls, apache, ssl

I have a standard wordpress installation with no plugins residing in /var/www/blog on my root server. It uses an Apache2, mod_rewrite, mod_ssl and that is configured just fine and works perfectly for anything but Wordpress.

My .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
#RewriteRule (.*)  http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somesite.info [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) https://somesite.info%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

A couple of things are wrong:

- I need http and https, `http://www.` and `https:/www.`
- FF displays my site just fine, Chrome loads the CSS and JS from http:// - that is bad

I have added the variables to the wp-config.php:

```
 define('WP_HOME','http:/somesite.info/blog');                                                                                                             
 define('WP_SITEURL','http://somesite.info/blog');
```

How can I define the variables so that all the 4 possible URL schemes get supported?
The shown rewrite conditions in comments make me end up in a redirect loop. 
My Wordpress is behind a reverse proxy, so I assume the .htacess stuff doesn't fit.

Best,
ww

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a plugin for this called [WordPress HTTPS](http://www.mvied.com/projects/wordpress-https/). If you still intend to code a solution yourself, maybe you can get some ideas from it at least.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [WordPress is_ssl() not working behind reverse proxies](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/wordpress-is_ssl-doesnt-work-behind-some-load-balancers/) and install the [SSL Insecure Content Fixer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/) plugin so that you can easily test whether you can add a fix based on `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']`; see that plugin's [FAQ](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/faq/).

If you have the misfortune to be hosted by Network Solutions, you can fix your problem by installing [this simple plugin](https://gist.github.com/webaware/4688802) and setting your home and site URLs to use https: full time.